(New Zorin OS user) Can't run Steam games unless on my SSD/install drive, and those I can run are excessively slow
I'm having some trouble. This is my first attempt at Linux and I'm already running into a wall. I installed the normal version of the latest Zorin OS on my SSD because the nvidia version failed twice. The only other things on the SSD now are "Steam installer," some other flatpack (?) store apps, Kingdom Come: Deliverance, Proton, and a very small game I downloaded to test if I could play games. I can play them, but KCD stutters like my rig is 20 years too old for it. It ran just fine last week on Win10 with my nvidia 1070 ti (though I couldn't launch it yesterday on win10, which is what prompted me to finally give linux a shot). I downloaded the nvidia drivers so I dunno what this is about.
I have a lot of other games on my external HDD that steam recognizes but won't actually launch. I'm not sure what that's about, either. Steam will install vulkan shaders if and then... nothing. I also have two internal HDDs with an install of Win7 and Win10 that I haven't been booting from (via BIOS config). Kinda just hoping this isn't a problem but if setting up dual boot would fix my problems then I'll have to take care of it I guess.
I went through these instructions and at least I seem to have nvidia drivers now, but I'm not sure if they're not installed properly or my PC can't properly access my hardware. https://old.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1577jej/steam_games_refusing_to_launch/jt4zior/


If you have Nvidia graphics and intend to play games you do need the Nvidia proprietary drivers. 2. Zorin isn't a good choice for beginners because it's just an Ubuntu derivative and not official; it lacks support for many things that otherwise searching Ubuntu would be easy to find; Namely you may need to understand how to install unsigned drivers and deal with Secure Boot. 3. Steam installed via SNAP is confined; you may need to enable access to additional locations under /media or /mnt.

